# how to discard git local branch changes?

Tags: git

how to discard git local branch changes? 
eg, local branch with version: A->B->C
Now I am on version A, and it has some changes conflict with latest version C.
I want to discard local changes and pull the latest version C.

```
$ git pull
```

I will meet some error. and there are many files, so I don't need to do many times `$ git co files`

Is there any better way?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

If you have uncommitted changes that you want to discard, use this:

```
$ git reset --hard
```

which is equivalent to

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

This removes all the local uncommitted changes. If you want to remove some offending commits from your local branch, try rewinding it:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD^ #moves HEAD back by one commit
```

or e.g.

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD~3 #moves HEAD back by 3 commits
```

Use these with caution, as you won't be able to undo these operations. Once you're done cleaning up your local branch, use `git pull` to get the latest code.

Comment: If you have already pushed your branch to a remote server you need to be careful with reset --hard as it can mess up the history.

Comment: That doesn't delete the uncommitted files.  You would have to delete these files manually.

Answer (score 38):

```
git fetch
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: `git reset --hard origin/master` is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: this is assuming you ave checked in to the remote at some point, does the same apply to local repos? can i do `git reset --hard otherLocalBranch` for the same effect?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for to discard commits I pulled from another branch by mistake. Thanks @Onlyjob

Answer (score 1):

Have you already commited your local changes?
If not a git reset --hard HEAD should do the trick

Comment: You can also undo locally committed changes, see ayoy's solution.