# How to completely discard changes made on a topic branch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, reset

In a topic branch I wrongly duplicated a model and a migration (previously created in the master branch) with:

```
rails generate model User name:string email:string 
bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

The duplicate model was created but the migration failed because the database already had a `users` table. Following instructions in [how to discard git local branch changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846699/how-to-discard-git-local-branch-changes), I tried to discard all uncommitted changes with `git reset --hard`, but `git status` still shows presence of untracked files:

```
# Untracked files:
# (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    app/models/user.rb
    db/migrate/
    test/fixtures/users.yml
    test/models/user_test.rb

# nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Why did `git reset --hard` preserve these files? What can I do to safely remove this files in order to completely reset the topic branch to the last commit? Would `rails destroy model User` suit me?

Comment: try with `git reset HEAD` .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I remove local (untracked) files from my current Git branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/61212/how-do-i-remove-local-untracked-files-from-my-current-git-branch)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @HBHB already correctly said: `git reset --hard` resets just tracked files.

However you can also remove untracked files using git by calling [`git clean -df`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean). `-d` removes also untracked directories and `-f` (force) has to be provided or otherwise Git won't delete the files.

Comment: Thanks @RajarshiDas :)

Answer (score 1):

These files are not tracked by git (note they are listed under "Untracked files" in the `git status` output). `git reset --hard` removes the changes in all files tracked by git. From the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) for `git reset --hard`:

> Resets the index and working tree. Any changes to tracked files in the working tree since **commit** are discarded.

To get rid of them, simply remove them:

```
rm app/models/user.rb
rm db/migrate/
rm test/fixtures/users.yml
rm test/models/user_test.rb
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git clean -f -d
```

would be safest bet to remove untracked files. Further you may look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64966/1381240)

Answer (score 0):

I always use this command:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

and

> rails git:(master) ✗ git reset --hard HEAD~1 HEAD is now at
>   45e2c462 Skip the pipeline for webpack