# git sync or reset with upstream branch

Tags: git, github

I do `git status` I got this

`Your branch is ahead of 'upstream/develop' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)`

I forgot what changes I made, I think I want sync with upstream branch, how to discard the commit, reset my code as same as my upstream branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to discard git local branch changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7846699/how-to-discard-git-local-branch-changes)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to revert past 1 commit, this will do:

```
$ git reset HEAD~1  # HEAD~2 if 2 commits and so on
```

Your last commit should be un-staged if you `git status` and then if you want to clean them:

```
$ git reset --hard  # resets changes
```

For untracked files you can use this:

```
$ git clean -fd
```

Then you can pull to upstream as desired. Hope this helps!